# Have I already ruined my 3 month old gaming PC?

Tags: windows, performance, administrator

I "built" this pc through the nzxt program and I have had it since May 25th.  I use it for gaming anything from madden to World of Warcraft Classic. I wanted to build a PC that could run wow in 4k hdr and even a little beyond because I had some extra money and why not?

Ill attach the invoice of the build as an image to this message. So, over the past month especially I have gone down the rabbit hole of why am I not "admin of that user" and "how did my wife just wake up my pc from sleep without a passcode and go through my email "(because the PCs administrator won't require a code when waking from sleep.)

These are just a few of several examples of things that I didn't understand and I began downloading , malwarebytes, Norton 360, bitdefender, Total AV, Avast, and all those things at one time in the past 3 months.  The computer is obviously so slow compared to when I opened it, I am so worried I ruined it by just snooping around and clicking permissions and being an idiot like that because I was frustrated why I can't open a file even though I own the computer.

It's obvious I have a lack of knowledge on how to maintain a pc and keep it optimized and working smoothly.  I know I am a moron for not learning more before playing around with settings on such an expensive piece of equipment. So now avast and nordvpn are on it for utilities, but now it is always a slow, buggy computer, it even has those black rectangles that pop up every 10 min or so on the desktop for half a second and it disappears.

I am no longer touching settings until I get professional advice. Also, the guide I found on making a system recovery image is the version where you choose in settings to make a recovery image and it mentions windows 7, so I figure I did that incorrectly also.

What should I do? is there any software that can actually fix this and get this pc back to as original as possible? It's difficult to explain but the computer can do basically every task required, but its just so much slower now and theres random popups , not popups like ads on a browser, like a quick half of the left screen goes black then back to normal.

I apologize that I am not better at describing the issues I am having.  Btw the "windows 7 recovery" i made after having the PC an entire month, so it was in better shape then, but nothing near what it was originally. I have the recovery on a 1tb portable ssd.   Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hello, this is unreadable, I'd recommend getting familiar with paragraphs. Regardless, the question from the title is opinion-based and it shouldn't be. Ask a specific question regarding fixing a part of the system or hardware instead.

Comment: Mostpeoplewillnottaketimetodecodeasolidwalloftext. Including me.

Comment: You installed a bunch of software that runs when the computer starts. The solution is simple. Uninstall a bunch of stuff and make sure that the correct programs start when the computer starts. Start by uninstalling Norton 360, BitDefender, Total AV, Avast and NordVPN.

Comment: Do you know which Windows version you have? If you press and hold the Windows key, then press the R key, then release a new screen will pop up called "Run". Type `winver` (short for Windows Version) in the box and press Enter). It will tell you which version of Windows you are on.

Comment: Many PC support shops offer some kind of clean / refresh PC type package. If you don't know where to start yourself, that might be an option. But first step is basically getting rid of all the junk you seem to have installed. You can bring any PC to it's knees provided you install enough junk.

Comment: And for the record, you have not "ruined" anything, if a nerd spends 5-10 minutes the pc is back to working like it did when it was new.

Comment: `malwarebytes, Norton 360, bitdefender, Total AV, Avast` yeah, installing 5 antivirus programs probably isn't the best idea - even if you THINK you've uninstalled them, some of those are notorious for leaving crud behind - I hope you don't have them all running at the same time!!!

Comment: Your hardware is likely fine - this would be a software problem.  There is not enough information to tell you how to fix it (could be lots of combinations of lots of things) but pull up task manager and sort by CPU and see what is eating your resources.   Also, do you have an SSD or HDD.  HDD's are a major bottleneck and it can get worse with fragmentation.  (Your invoice / BOM did not come through).

Comment: I posted an answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1804181/1482432

Comment: If you indeed installed multiple antivirus programs, its common that they will fight each other. Reason: Each time you access a file, one AV will scan it, then another will detect file access and scan it too, then the first detects the second one accessing the file and scan it to, and before you know it, they are constantly scanning the same file. Especially with more than 2, the usage increases exponentially. Get one AV and stick to that one.

Answer (score 2):

How do we learn? By making mistakes and fixing them.

OK, lets do this step by step.

### First we check which programs are installed on the computer.

1. Press the Windows key on your keyboard, or leftclick on the Windows button.

[image]

2. Type "settings" and then press Enter.

[image]

3. A new window appears. On the left-hand side, click on Apps.

[image]

4. Then click on "Installed Apps" on the right-hand side of the Settings window.

[image]

5. On the right-hand side you will see every installed program on your computer. You can certainly uninstall Malwarebytes, Norton 360, Bitdefender, Total AV & Avast. If there are any programs you are unsure about, let us know and we will tell you if they can be deleted.

You see the name of the program, and then in smaller letters below that who made it. Anything made by the Microsoft Corporation you can certainly keep. For example:

[image]

Whoohooo! Step 1 done.

---

### Now let's check which programs start when you start the computer.

1. Right-click an empty area of that bar in the bottom of the screen. The icons on your screen will be different, and on your screen it will probably be grey instead of black,

[image]

2. A small window will pop up, with 2 options: Task Manager and Taskbar settings. Click on Task Manager.
3. A new window will appear. It looks a bit like this:

[image]

It is possible that you only see the icons and not the names on the left hand side.

4. Click on Startup Apps (or the icon that looks like a speed dial on a car)
5. On the right-hand side you see which apps start when the computer starts. If you tell us which ones there are, then we can tell you which apps to disable. If you right-click one of the programs in the list you'll see the option to disable it (which means to stop it from starting when the computer starts). The changes will take effect the next time you start the computer.

Whoohooo! Step 2 is done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like, at some point, something got installed that perhaps should not have been.

It's unclear exactly what that is exactly though, and it is possible there is some hardware issue at play.

I would recommend reinstalling windows. I think this might be the most foolproof way of giving the machine the best chance at working like new and it may help determine if it is a hardware or software issue.

Look into the following steps

- copy important files to an external drive
- create a bootable windows 10/11 installer disk
- boot from the usb installer disk
- install windows 10/11
- install drivers for the hardware included in your system

This of course takes a significant amount of time and effort. It is possible to feel stuck or not be sure how to make progress. If it is your first time doing this, I would recommend finding someone local who could help you work out any kinks along the way.

If you can pull it off, you should feel much more confident in the future to experiment with different settings and application installations knowing you can always get back to a working system.

Comment: Don't use a sledgehammer to kill a mosquito.

Comment: @Gantendo You are right there may be a less invasive way, but I think reinstalling would probably give the OP the confidence to experiment, knowing he can always get back to a working system even if it takes the nuclear option

Comment: In my experience, if you tell people who don't use PC's as often as we do to reinstall their computer they never get it back in a working state and they are eternally confused. Making backups and reinstalling software is easy if you know what you are doing, but if you don't it is nearly impossible.

Comment: That's a valid concern. I will update the answer to reflect that possibility.

Comment: Yes I am afraid that is what I would do @Gantendo 8